# Problem getting substring in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string variable having data

```
4096;jpg,bmp
```

or

```
2048;flv,mpg
```

I want to split this string into two string in jquery on the basis of ;

Comment: You should learn about the difference between JavaScript and jQuery. jQuery is just a library focused on manipulating a web page. Simple operations like this are done directly in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's [`split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function.

```
var some_text = "blah;blah;blahness";
var arr = some_text.split(';');
alert(arr[2]); //blahness
```

Answer (score 1):

here is some code..

```
var str = '4096;jpg,bmp';
var elements = str.split(';');

alert( elements[0] ); // 4096
alert( elements[1] ); // jpg,bmp
```